# Create a button to download file on cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using cakephp 2.5

I have a file named XXX.zip which is located in webroot/downloadable. I would like to create a button in Cakephp that allows the user to click and download this file. How should the code in cakephp look like? I suppose this code should reside in view and will look something like this;

```
echo $this->Form->button('Submit', array('type' => 'submit'));
```

But how do I insert the file location information? File to be downloaded resides in webroot/downloadable folder.

Comment: please take a look at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-files

Comment: Is it not enough to link content right away? I mean with just a link to www.domain.com/downloadable/file your browser will take care of such download.

Comment: @LuisClemente: this won't work in my case because the file needs to be created first before the link works. Clicking the button will create the zipped file first, then provide the link for user to download the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CakeResponse::file() to send a file on request.

The cakephp cookbook describes this relatively easy task very good.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cake-response-file

Comment: THanks for the reply. I now know how to handle the controller part. I can create a controller function called downloadFile. But how about the view part? I would like to add a button in my view.ctp that allows the user to download the file.

Comment: Check this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html and search for button.